# Reducing rows if they have same values in certain columns

Tags: r

I am using r and the problem I have is that I want unique time 1 and time 2 values for each id & date, but for some rows, they are separated. I want to combine the rows that have same values in certain columns by combining values of columns.

Specifically, if 'id' and 'date' match, I want to reduce two rows to one.

```
id <- c('A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'C'); date <- c('2023-10-09', "2023-10-10", "2023-10-10", "2023-10-10", "2023-10-10")
time1 <- c('2023-10-09 05:55:55', '2023-10-10 05:55:55', NA, NA, '2023-10-10 10:55:55')
time2 <- c('2023-10-09 06:10:55', NA, '2023-10-10 20:55:55', '2023-10-10 20:59:55', NA)
df <- data.frame(id, date, time1, time2)
> df
  id       date               time1               time2
1  A 2023-10-09 2023-10-09 05:55:55 2023-10-09 06:10:55
2  B 2023-10-10 2023-10-10 05:55:55                <NA>
3  C 2023-10-10                <NA> 2023-10-10 20:55:55
4  B 2023-10-10                <NA> 2023-10-10 20:59:55
```

What I want is

```
id <- c('A', 'B', 'C'); date <- c('2023-10-09', "2023-10-10", "2023-10-10")
time1 <- c('2023-10-09 05:55:55', '2023-10-10 05:55:55','2023-10-10 10:55:55')
time2 <- c('2023-10-09 06:10:55', '2023-10-10 20:55:55', '2023-10-10 20:59:55')
df <- data.frame(id, date, time1, time2)
> df
  id       date               time1               time2
1  A 2023-10-09 2023-10-09 05:55:55 2023-10-09 06:10:55
2  B 2023-10-10 2023-10-10 05:55:55 2023-10-10 20:55:55
3  C 2023-10-10 2023-10-10 10:55:55 2023-10-10 20:59:55
```

Any input will be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```r
library(dplyr)

df |>
  mutate(time1 = min(time1, na.rm = TRUE), 
         time2 = max(time2, na.rm = TRUE),
         .by = c(id, date)) |>
  unique()
#>   id       date               time1               time2
#> 1  A 2023-10-09 2023-10-09 05:55:55 2023-10-09 06:10:55
#> 2  B 2023-10-10 2023-10-10 05:55:55 2023-10-10 20:59:55
#> 3  C 2023-10-10 2023-10-10 10:55:55 2023-10-10 20:55:55
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>